# Droppable, paramter "hoverClass" with condition, jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have following html:

```
<div class="square draggable"></div>
<div class="circle draggable"></div>

<div class="square_box droppable"></div>
<div class="circle_box droppable"></div>
```

I need to use hover style enabled only when shape of draggable and droppable object match.

I'm using jQuery UI drag-and-drop

```
jQuery('.droppable').droppable( {
  ***
  hoverClass: 'hovered',
  ***
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`accept`](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept) option like:

```
$('.square_box').droppable({
   accept: '.square'
});
```

If you have so many shapes, define the relationships as an array of key-value pairs, iterate over it and initialize them as droppable.

Comment: Excellent solution! Thanks a lot!